# Group by por 3 parametros de un data class Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

Hola en este código https://github.com/Miguel546/groupbykotlin en la clase GroupBy.kt estoy queriendo hacer un group by de 3 elementos de un data class de 16 elementos.

Mediante el siguiente código

`val pal =paletas?.groupBy {it.LoadNumber; it.PalNum; it.Estado}`

El resultado se agrupa por Estado por un elemento pero necesito que sea por 3 atributos del data class **LoadNumber**, **PalNum**, **Estado**.

Este es el código.

```
val string = "json"
    val moshi = Moshi.Builder().add(KotlinJsonAdapterFactory())
        .build()
    val type = Types.newParameterizedType(MutableList::class.java, Paleta::class.java)
    val adapter = moshi.adapter<MutableList<Paleta>>(type)
    val paletas: MutableList<Paleta>? = adapter.fromJson(string)
    val paletasSize = paletas?.size?:0
    for(i in 0  until paletasSize){
        println(paletas?.get(i))
    }

    val pal =paletas?.groupBy {
        it.LoadNumber; it.PalNum; it.Estado
    }

    println(pal)
```

El print solo me agrupa por estado adjunto imágenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el data class Paleta.

```
@JsonClass(generateAdapter = true)
data class Paleta(
    @field:Json(name = "Nro")
    var Nro: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "LoadNumber")
    val LoadNumber: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "PalNum")
    val PalNum: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "Plant")
    val Plant: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "LogisticLot")
    val LogisticLot: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "SKU")
    val SKU: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "WorkId")
    val WorkId: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "CentRecSAP")
    val CentRecSAP: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "UOM")
    val UOM: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "Quantity")
    val Quantity: Double?,
    @field:Json(name = "LotGeneric")
    val LotGeneric: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "FlagPaleta")
    val FlagPaleta: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "Estado")
    var Estado: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "CT")
    val CT: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "Num_Transporte")
    val Num_Transporte: String?,
    @field:Json(name = "Flag_Proc")
    val Flag_Proc: String?
)
```

Se agrupa por uno pero no por tres. ¿se puede agrupar por los 3 parámetros **LoadNumber**, **PalNum**, **Estado** del data class Paleta en kotlin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que sucede es que el resultado del bloque `groupBy` está tomando el estado como clave. Para usar una clave compuesta por los tres valores, puedes usar un `Triple` de la siguiente manera:

```
val pal = paletas?.groupBy {
   Triple(it.LoadNumber, it.PalNum, it.Estado)
}
```